# SyntaxError: invalid syntax python nltk

Tags: python, nltk, defaultdict

Hi i'm currently learning python and I have an error i cant get rid of. It says :

```
import nltk

  File "/home/yxnisss/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 128, in <module

from nltk.collocations import *

  File "/home/yxnisss/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 35, in <module

from nltk.probability import FreqDist
 
 File "/home/yxnisss/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/probability.py", line 333
    print("%*s" % (width, samples[i]), end=" ")
                                          ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I dont even no what to do.
I've search if anyone had already have this problem but all the answers didn't work for me.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Get Python 3 already. Python 2 is past end of life, and nltk no longer supports it.

Comment: You're trying to run Python 3 code in a Python 2 interpreter.

Comment: so what should i do ?

Comment: Upgrade to a Python 3 interpreter.

Comment: i already have python3 thats the problem

Comment: That error message says you're not using it.

Comment: You likely need to specify `python3` instead of `python` when running it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to run Python3 code in a Python2.7 interpreter.

Your error messages state that you are using `python2.7`, specify `python3` when running your script as such: `python3 file.py`